# AZURE - Cannot access to Webapp located in ASE

Tags: azure, web-applications, ase

I have the following problem: I created an ASE (App Service Environment) in terms of having an isolated WebApp connected between some VPN.

I created an internal VNET where that ASE is located. The problem is: when I create the WebApp, it has the same IP than the VIP associated to the ASE. So I am not able to connect to the WebApp.

I need help guys!

Comment: what type of ASE did you create? External or Internal? Did you host any app on that ASE?